What is the difference between intentions and desires?
What is the difference between intentions and desires?
Do they have different usage context, or is there difference in meaning?

Usual question - what have you learned from using dictionaries?

That intentions are some what similar to desires except they have plans to achieve that but desires are just like what you want but no plans to achieve that.I am just asking this question to make sure this understanding is true.

Hi! Please use the "edit" button to add your comment to the question itself. Comments aren't "official" or permanent. It's also nice if you mention which dictionary you checked and quote it, just in case it's misleading or you've misunderstood it. But you're on the right track, and I'll go ahead and answer.

Desires can be things you want to; intentions are things you plan to do.

You're right: The main difference is that "intention" means a plan. One way to understand the difference between words is to find times that one works and the other doesn't.
"Desire" means you want to do it; "intend" means you plan to do it. So maybe you plan to do something that you don't like:

I intend to go to work tomorrow

... even though you hate going to work. You don't desire to, but you intend to.
Or, maybe you want something but don't have a way to get it...

One of my secret desires has always been to ride a unicorn.

I desire to, but I don't intend to, since it's impossible. Or maybe it's something that's possible, but I just don't have a plan to do it any time soon:

I've always had a secret desire to learn ballroom dancing.

There's nothing stopping me from signing up for classes, but I just don't plan to.
Note, I had a hard time making an example sentence for this one that uses the word "desire," since it would often be more natural to use "want." "I've always wanted to learn to dance!" "I've always wanted to visit Spain!" That might be because "desire" has connotations of wanting something strongly (especially in modern usage), and it's hard to imagine many things that we want strongly, and can do, but don't actually plan for.
Of course, you're probably asking this question because there are many contexts in which you both desire and intend.

My intent/desire for my children is that they grow into healthy adults.

It's what I want, and as far as it's in my power, it's my plan. The word you choose depends on which part you want to emphasize.

For your struggle, consider desiring something illicit, illegal, or immoral. A person might desire it strongly, but never plan to obtain it because ^

@DaleM Sure, but "I desire some cocaine" is still not idiomatic compared to "geez, I really want some cocaine. I chose not to elaborate, but I'm thinking that maybe "desire" has been waning in use as a verb, replaced with "want," but "desire" stays in our vocabulary because it's a more convenient noun for talking about our "wanting." (Meanwhile, "want" as a noun is decidedly archaic and had a different meaning, a lack. There's also a specialized modern usage "needs vs wants," but that's fairly rare.)

This ngram supports this notion: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=desire_NOUN%2Cdesire_VERB%2Cwant_NOUN%2Cwant_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3
